# Windows Service in WCF Advantages

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

We currently have a bunch of windows services. I am wondering what the advantages would be of making these WCF Windows Services?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what the services do.  If you have no need for them to communicate with other programs, then there isn't really much of a point. We have several services which check the health of the database, process files etc.  Would it be nice if other services could communicate with them, yes maybe, but they don't need to at the moment, so we don't add extra code we don't need to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At the moment they simply retrieve data from a queue and process it. Similarly to you, perhaps it would be nice for other services to communicate with them, but there certainly isn't a requirement at present. I was wondering whether WAS was perhaps one benefit, in that you don't need to worry about the deployment so much and then inherit some of the IIS features.